# Rails 4: Included CSS Files Not Working

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-4

This may be a CSS, not a Rails issue.

I have added additional CSS files to app/assets/stylesheets, including one called buttons.css. The rules in buttons.css are not working. However, if I copy-paste those rules to custom.css, the rules work just fine.

Application.css contains:

```
*= require_self
 *= require_tree .
```

Generated HTML shows that the files are being included by Rails:

```
<link href="/assets/buttons.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/assets/custom.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet">
```

There are many other added .css files in this folder as well, including others that affect the .button class and .button pseudo-classes. Is it possible that other rules are getting in the way?

Comment: It could a problem with the load order. A css file loaded after buttons.css may be overriding it's rules.

Comment: Tom, I wondered about that, but I'm not sure how to change the load order in Rails. Any ideas?

Comment: Explicitly require the files in the necessary order. E.g. `*= require custom` followed by `*= require buttons` and put them before `*= require_tree .` .